# Add database name to "sys.views"

Tags: sql-server

Can we add database name to sys.views?

```
select * from sys.views
```

Comment: Why don't you try in a sandbox system?

Comment: Sorry did not get you

Comment: What database system is this? What columns do you get from your current query? Have you checked the manual, or looked for other system tables you might be able to JOIN to to get a database name?

Comment: @manishp, I mean that you should do some minimal research before asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sys.views only returns views for the current database, so technically you would just ...

```
SELECT DB_NAME(), * FROM sys.views
```